# how to replace the first 8 elements of last column of array(size = (8,8,3 )) with 2d array of size (8,8) using python

Tags: python

i have two arrays of size (8,8,3) and (8,8). 
the first 8 elements of last column of first 3D array has to be replaced by elements of last 2D array using python.

basically m working on images of different sizes. m extracting the blue part of image, doing some calculations on it and replacing it back. the extracted blue part is forming a mxn array whereas the original image has dim= mxnxk.

m currently working on image of size (4,4,3) which will be extended for image of higher dimension. here img is image havg dimension = (4,4,3) and q is array derived from some calculations which results in size (4,4).

```
img = cv2.imread("ori.jpg")
print(img)

img[:,2] = q       #here q is an 4x4 array
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\fresh_seminar\wm_E && extract.py", line 195, in 
    img[:,2] = q
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (4,4) into shape (4,3)

this is the error i get for the last code line

Comment: `replaced by elements of last 2D array`?

Comment: please show your code and what is it that you are having difficulty with

Comment: yes elements of 2D array @Shijith

Comment: a (4,4,3) array means **four**  `4x3` arrays together, you cannot assign a `4x4` array back to a `4x3` array

Comment: @AlbinPaul i have posted my code. please check up.

Comment: Actually i have extracted the last column of img array, did some calculations on it and now i want to replace it back. @Shijith is there a way to replace that?

Comment: `print(np.ones((4,4,3), dtype=np.int))`, print this out and see how a 4x4x3 array is structured,

Comment: what is the shape of `img[:,2]` and `q`?

Comment: yes it is structured and dimensions are specified in the question @Shijith

Comment: `_Actually i have extracted the last column of img array_`, how did you extract, what is the shape of the extracted array?

Comment: b = img[:,:,0]
size of b = (4, 4)
b = [[178 210 177 195]
       [152 191 153 165]
        [117 138 101 114]
       [157 138 100 138]]

Comment: please someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for such a long time i finally found the answer.
Replacing the array b with part of sample image array can be done with the following code. i know its simple but it took me a lot of time to get that!

```
b = np.ones((8,8), dtype = int)     #array b of size(8,8) to be replaced
half_cover = cv2.imread("sample.jpg")  
print(half_cover)
print(half_cover.shape)              shape = (894, 894, 3)  

for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        half_cover[i,j] = b[i,j]
print(half_cover)
```